# Google couldn't follow your URL because it redirected too many times

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, google-search-console

I was fixing url's on a website, and one of the problems there was that the url's contained characters that were sometimes upper-case while other times lower-case, the server did not care about it, but google did, and indexed the pages as duplicates.
Also some urls contained characters that are simply not allowed to be in that part of the URL, like commas "," and brackets "()" although [round brackets are technically not reserved][1]
I still decided to get rid of them by encoding them.

I added a check that checks if the url is valid, and if not, would do a 301 redirect to the correct url.

for example
http://www.example.com/articles/SomeGreatArticle(2012).html
would do a 301 redirect to
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle%282012%29.html

It works, and it does one redirect to the correct url.

But for a small fraction of the pages (which are possibly the only pages google has indexed so far) google webmaster tools started to give me the following error under the Crawl errors > Not followed tab:

> Google couldn't follow your URL because it redirected too many
>   times.

googling for this error with quotes gives me 0 results, and I'm sure I'm not the only one to ever get this error, so I would like to know some more information about it, for example:

1. how many redirects can a single page do before google thinks that it's too many?
2. what are the other possible causes for such an error?

Comment: More information and the page that is creating this error would be helpful to determine the issue.

Comment: @ErikdR added links, what kind of information would you want to know?

Comment: Found info http://www.monperrus.net/martin/google+url+encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

According to this experiment http://www.monperrus.net/martin/google+url+encoding

Google has it's own character encoding rules, where google will always encode some characters and always decode other.

The following characters are never encoded

```
-,.@~_*)!$'(
```

So even if you give Google this url

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle%282012%29.html
```

where the round brackets () are encoded, google will transform this URL, decode the brackets and follow this URL instead:

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle(2012).html
```

**What happened in my situation:**

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle(2012).html
```

my server would do a 301 redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle%282012%29.html
```

while Googlebot would ignore the encoded brackets and follow:

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle(2012).html
```

get redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle%282012%29.html
```

follow

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle(2012).html
```

get redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/articles/somegreatarticle%282012%29.html
```

and give up after a couple of tries and show the "**Google couldn't follow your URL because it redirected too many times**" error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Google webmaster tools, but I have seen a similar error in PHP, when there is an infinite loop of redirection. Make sure that none of the pages is redirecting to itself.

Comment: opening the page in the browser works fine, I don't how google is managing to get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Oke first of all I would remove the () and , signs from the urls, it is a fact that googlebot has a harder time working with these. And they don't do any benefit for SEO purposes either.
Readability for the client isn't an issues so if i where you just use a - or _ dash.
Try not to use any other character in your file/folder names.

You should also clean up your html, there are quite some errors and issues to resolve.

A cleaner source is better for google, browsers and your visitors.

I couldn't find any definitive problem that google would have an issue with.

Comment: It's a huge job to clean up the whole site, so I'm doing it one step at a time, and I am removing the brackets right now. I wonder why google has trouble with the redirects though.

Comment: Do you have anything special setup in your .htaccess like 301 redirects?

Comment: It's not an apache server, it uses nginx and that is an good question, I'll check tomorrow. Although I doubt there is anything that targets specifically search engines. Also, wouln't I see the redirection in a normal browser?

Comment: Not if its a .htaccess redirect or similar. The server would catch the url and send you to the correct one.